# Python time difference in if statements

Tags: python, datetime, if-statement, time

I'm quite new to python and having some problems regarding the `if` statements and the datetime module. The program takes the time when a button is pressed and another when it is released. It then subtracts start from finish to get the time difference. How do I use the time difference in `if` statement to perform a specific task? Here is my code:

```
from datetime import datetime

start = datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)
finish = datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)
total = (finish - start)

if(total > 0:00:08):
    #do something
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `date`? Did you do `from datetime import datetime as date` before? Did you take a look at `total` - is it a `timedelta` object?

Comment: Try to avoid import statements like this. The name `date` is already taken by the `date`-__class__ of the `datetime` __module__, so you might not want to rename the `datetime` __class__ from the `datetime` __module__ to `date`. As you see, things get confusing if you do renamings like this. I suggest to do `from datetime import datetime`, then write `datetime.now()`.

Comment: Yea i did mean datetime and i dont know what the "as date" is doing there. to much work and not enough sleep i think

Comment: @ChrisMeek Since you wrote `date.now()` I added the `as date` to make it run. So I guess this is my bad. Changed it to `datetime.now()`, will be visible after peer review.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The value you get from subtracting one date from another is a `timedelta` object. That has a method, `total_seconds()`, which not surprisingly gives you the total number of seconds, which you can compare against.

```
if total.total_seconds() > 8:
```

Note though that your code is invalid, since dates have no `now()` method: you meant `datetime`.

Answer (score 3):

Use timedelta, https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

```
from datetime import datetime
start = datetime.now()
finish = datetime.now()

total = finish - start

if (total.seconds > 8):
    # do something
```

For button press and release total.seconds would be fine, delta calculations are in days, seconds and microseconds so if your difference will be more than that of days then you should use total_seconds(), on the other hand using total_seconds() is always safe option.

Answer (score 2):

Subtracting the two `datetime` objects will yield a `timedelta`. You can compare this against some fixed `timedelta`, like 6 seconds in the example below.

```
if (total > datetime.timedelta(0, 6)):
    # do something
```

> [datetime.timedelta](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects)  All arguments are optional and default to 0. Arguments may be ints, longs, or floats, and may be positive or negative.

```
class datetime.timedelta([days[, seconds[, microseconds[, milliseconds[, minutes[, hours[, weeks]]]]]]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
from datetime import datetime

start = datetime.now()
finish = datetime.now()

delta = finish - start

if delta.total_seconds() > 5:
   # do something
```

- You have to use datetime and not date.
- subtracting or adding two times gives you timedelta
- You have use delta.total_seconds() to get the difference in seconds, delta.seconds will only return the seconds part of the difference